# Qual a diferença entre "/" e "%" em python?

Tags: python

```
x1 = int(input())
v1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
v2 = int(input())

if x1 == x2 and v1 == v2:
  print('SIM')

elif (x1 == x2) and (v1 != v2):
  print('NÃO')

elif (x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) == 0:
  if (x1 - x2) / (v2 - v1) > 0:
    print('SIM')
  else: print('NAO')

else: print('NAO')
```

Fiz esse código e percebi que o `%` e o `/` mudam totalmente o resultado. Qual a diferença entre eles?

Comment: ```%``` pega o resto da divisao ```/ ``` operdaor de divisão normal em alguns casos(python 2.7) pega so a parte inteira da divisao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python possui alguns operadores aritméticos, estes são:

```
+   Adição
-   Subtração
*   Multiplicação
/   Divisão 
//  Divisão Inteira
%   Módulo 
**  Exponenciação
```

Cada operador tem sua função e deve ser utilizado para alcançar determinado fim. Ao utilizar o operador de `divisão (/)` você estará obtendo o resultado da divisão entre dois valores, já o operador `módulo (%)`, dentro de uma operação, retornará o resto da divisão entre dois valores.

Ex:

`5/2 = 2.5`

`5%2 = 1`